# ERROR #98123 WEBPACK.BUILD-JAVASCRIPT Generating JavaScript bundles failed while building gatsby site

Tags: javascript, webpack, gatsby

I've been trying to build my `gatsby` site but the build is failing with an error as

```bash
failed Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 7.408s

 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK.BUILD-JAVASCRIPT

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

styles.41cdc950875b04ce14b3.css from Css Minimizer
/Users/rit/proj1/styles.41cdc950875b04ce14b3.css:1175:18: Unknown word [styles.41cdc950875b04ce14b3.css:1175,18]
    at Input.error (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:106:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:593:22)
    at Parser.other (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:435:12)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:470:16)
    at parse (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/postcss/lib/parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:133:16)
    at Processor.process (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:53:14)
    at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js:34:28), <anonymous>:51:61)
    at minify (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js:15:32)
    at Object.transform (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js:35:24)

File: styles.41cdc950875b04ce14b3.css


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK.BUILD-JAVASCRIPT

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

styles.d9f8181dfdee20ae152d.css from Css Minimizer
/Users/rit/proj1/styles.d9f8181dfdee20ae152d.css:1175:18: Unknown word [styles.d9f8181dfdee20ae152d.css:1175,18]
    at Input.error (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:106:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:593:22)
    at Parser.other (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:435:12)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:470:16)
    at parse (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/postcss/lib/parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:133:16)
    at Processor.process (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:53:14)
    at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js:34:28), <anonymous>:51:61)
    at minify (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js:15:32)
    at Object.transform (/Users/rit/proj1/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js:35:24)

File: styles.d9f8181dfdee20ae152d.css

not finished Running gatsby-plugin-sharp.IMAGE_PROCESSING jobs - 7.927s
```

### Some context

To install the packages I use - `npm i -f` ( as there are some dependency issues ). It installs successfully.

The develop works fine - `npm run dev`

However, when I try to run `npm run build` it fails with the error above. I am not sure how to even debug this, as I can't find those files in here on my system.

`Unknown word [styles.d9f8181dfdee20ae152d.css:1175,18]`

### Update 1

I realised that removing all the css from `global.css` file allows for getting the build working. Though even before there was this file with css in it and the build used to pass that time.

Answer (score 0):

So on going commit by commit to find where the code started breaking, I figured it was the `tailwind.config.js`.

In tailwind, inline `code` element also has a backtick with it '`'. To remove this I followed a comment here - https://github.com/orgs/remarkjs/discussions/674#discussioncomment-5387785

However, `&nbsp;` was the reason the build was failing. Hence, I changed it to `none`. Now it's building fine.

Here's the config diff
[image]

Thanks everyone.